# Get property types from generic T without using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a sorting/filtering class that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` for data and a object that contains the sorting/filtering conditions.

I am building expressions to then execute over the collection.

```c#
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
Expression left = splitFilter.Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

var constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value.Text.ToLower(), typeof(string));
var body = Expression.Call(MakeString(left, constant), "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, constant);
Expression bodyNullCheck = CheckForNullableParameters(left, body);
Expression<Func<T, bool>> ex = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(bodyNullCheck, parameter);
```

Example data structure:

```c#
public class Customer
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<StoreItem> BoughtItems {get; set;}
}
public class StoreItem
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The solution works great for things that have a depth of 1 for example:
Here we can easily retrieve all Customers that have "t" in their name.

**The problem comes when we wish to get all customers which have bought an item which contains "Bag" in the name.**

From the front-end, I'm currently getting "BoughtItems.Name" but I can't seem to get into the "StoreItem" object even though I have the exact property name.

```c#
string[] splitFilter = filter.Key.Split('.'); // Contains  {"BoughtItems", "Name"}

Expression parent = new string[] { splitFilter[0] }.Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
Expression child = new string[] { splitFilter[1] }.Aggregate(parent, Expression.PropertyOrField);
```

Currently, I'm trying to get the expressions for both objects separately and then to somehow combine them, but if I try to get the type of the first expression  it says it can't access property Name of type Collection. (duuh)

Is there a way in C# to say "The items inside this Generic collection have this property, now using this property let's go down 1 layer and get another property?" (StoreItem.Name)

The result I'm trying to get should be semi-generic and give the same result as the example below, without using reflection.

```c#
string searchBy = "test";

var result = MyCustomers.Where(x => x.BoughtItems.Any(y => y.Name.Contains(searchBy))).ToList()
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to use reflection?

Comment: The only reason is performance.

Comment: You complain about performance. So what is your performance issue? Is it just a gut feeling or do you have any hard numbers? Reflection will be used in so many places within the framework and simply because you don't see it, you don't complain. But if you use it on yourself it immediately feels slow without any numbers to tell. So race your horses and tell us, where your performance problem is and not only, that you don't like to use reflection because it could be slow.

Comment: Also `Where(y => y.Any(y => y.Name.Contains(searchBy))))` looks completely wrong cause `y` is an `StoreItem`, not a collection of `StoreItem`'s.

Comment: @Oliver You are 100% correct and it is exactly as you described. The thing is, I was trying to find a solution that wouldn't use reflection, but the more I searched the more it was obvious that it would be used one way or another, so this was my last attempt to get a solution that would be "reflection-free". But since it is already used in ```Expression.Call``` I think it's a lost cause.

Comment: @Hafinator if performance is a problem - you should cache the generation results or parts of them (or reflection calls).

Comment: This is also a solution I came across regarding performance.

Comment: @Hafinator, why do you need to use expression, when `MyCustomers.Where(x => x.BoughtItems.Any(y => y.Name.Contains(searchBy))).ToList();` works perfectly fine?

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü because it is not static and should be build based on external request.

Answer (score 0):

As a personal preference, I like explicit over implicit. So unless you have an un-maintainable amount of different cases coming from front-end, you should implement each case explicitly.

Let us get back to the question at hand.
You would like to achieve the following expression tree from my understanding:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> exp = 
    myCustomer => myCustomer.BoughtItems.Any(storeItem => storeItem.Name.Contains("test"));
```

I like commenting my code extensively so from here on most of the time comments  will do the explaining :)

```
var myCustomerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "myCustomer");
var storeItemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StoreItem), "storeItem");

// This expression tree creates the following lambda
// storeItem => storeItem.Name.Contains("test")
var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StoreItem, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        // storeItem.Name
        Expression.Property(storeItemParameter, "Name"), 
        // storeItem.Name.Contains
        MethodSelectorExtensions.MethodSelector<string>("Contains", new[] {typeof(string)}),
        // storeItem.Name.Contains("test")
        Expression.Constant("test", typeof(string))
    ), 
    storeItemParameter
);

// This expression tree creates the following lambda
// myCustomer => Enumerable.Any(myCustomer.BoughtItems, storeItem => storeItem.Name.Contains("test")
var finalLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        // Since LINQ is extensions methods, it is static method, no instance is required
        null,
        // Enumerable.Any
        MethodSelectorExtensions.LinqMethodSelector("Any", new[] {typeof(IEnumerable<StoreItem>), typeof(Func<StoreItem, bool>)}),
        // Enumerable.Any(myCustomer.BoughtItems, storeItem => storeItem.Name.Contains("test"))
        Expression.Property(myCustomerParameter, "BoughtItems"), innerLambda
    ), 
    myCustomerParameter
);
```

Utility methods for creating Expressions

```
public static class MethodSelectorExtensions {

    /// <summary>
    /// Cached delegate to be used in typeof(Enumerable) methods
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Func<string, Type[], MethodInfo> EnumerableMethodSelector;

    /// <summary>
    /// Static ctor to cache EnumerableMethodSelector function
    /// </summary>
    static MethodSelectorExtensions() {
        var genericMethodSelector = typeof(MethodSelectorExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(MethodSelector), new[] {typeof(string), typeof(Type[])});
        // C# does not allow for static type generic methods but we can create through type system ;)
        EnumerableMethodSelector = (Func<string, Type[], MethodInfo>) genericMethodSelector.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Enumerable)).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, Type[], MethodInfo>));
    }

    public static MethodInfo MethodSelector<TType>(string nameOfMethod, Type[] functionParameterTypes) {
        return typeof(TType)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(n => n.Name == nameOfMethod)
            // in case we have TType as Enumerable, we will need to extract generic parameter
            .Select(n => n.IsGenericMethod ? n.MakeGenericMethod(functionParameterTypes[0].GenericTypeArguments[0]) : n)
            .Single(n => n.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(functionParameterTypes));
    }

    public static MethodInfo LinqMethodSelector(string nameOfMethod, Type[] functionParameterTypes) {
        return EnumerableMethodSelector(nameOfMethod, functionParameterTypes);
    }

}
```

And let us have a final look at the running program:

[image]

Comment: Don't know exactly what you did, but when I copied your code I get an exception:

Error cannot convert from `'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ExpressionTest.Customer, bool>>' to 'System.Func<ExpressionTest.Customer, bool>'`

and if I try to compile the expression and then use it the same way you do I get: 

`InvalidOperationException: System.Reflection.MethodInfo LinqMethodSelector(System.String, System.Type[]) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.`

Comment: @Hafinator, I did exactly what was asked in the question, proven by the screen shots and the created query. Since I do not know your codebase. I can not exactly guess what your problem is but as far as can tell, in the first error you are trying to pass an expression to an `IEnumerable<T>`? whereas you should pass a function. In the second error, you are mis-using the utility functions. Ask further if you cant solve the problems, more than happy to help

Comment: I was using my data structure with your code. I wasn't using dbContext but instead, I was using a list and for some reason the .Where() method does not want to take the finalLambda variable. Your first Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> exp =  example works after you I compiled the expression. I'm using the .Net core 3.1 if that makes any difference ( but I don't think it should)

Comment: @Hafinator You can not pass an `Expression< Func >` to an `IEnumerable`'s `Where` extension method. However, you can pass  `Expression< Func >` to `DbSet<T>`'s `Where` because it is an `IQueryable`. EDIT: After you compile an `Expression<Func>` you get a `Func` only, that is why you can pass it to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: yes I noticed that after I compile the expression it can then be passed to `IEnumerable` `Where` that makes so much sense, thank you. But when I Compile it and try to call your `MethodSelector<TType>` it throws `System.Reflection.MethodInfo LinqMethodSelector(System.String, System.Type[]) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.` For some reason, this line in your example throws an exception `MethodSelectorExtensions.MethodSelector<string>("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) })`

Comment: @Hafinator, Thank you very much for your feedback. I fixed the code. It looks like I made a copy paste error. It was `nameof(LinqMethodSelector)` (which is wrong). I changed it to  `nameof(MethodSelector)`